Entropy-conjugates: What can we say about them?
I have recently directed my attention to the fact that given any probability, i.e., a real number $p\epsilon\left[0,1\right]$, , there always exists another distinct probability, $p*\epsilon\left[0,1\right]$ , that produces the same amount of entropy in the sense that , $p\log{p}=p_\ast\log{p_\ast}$. Of course, the only exception is 1/e, for which $\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)_\ast=\frac{1}{e}$. Other examples are: $ 0_\ast=1, 1_\ast=0,\ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_\ast=\frac{1}{4}$.
While looking to understand the implications of this fact, I realized that, if we consider p* to be a function of p, and name it as y=y(x), then we conclude that this function needs to satisfy the following ODE: $y^\prime=(1+\ln\ x)/(1+\ln\ y\ )$ with y(0)=1. We also know that this function will be its own inverse.
As I'm not an ODE expert, I'd like to know if you can help me find what we can learn about the solution of this equation.
Many thanks.

By entropy do you mean  $-p\log p-(1-p)\log(1-p),?$

Hello @KurtG., thanks for the question. No, I mean the individual contributions of p and p* to the total entropy, that is, plogp and plogp. The conjugates have the same contribution.
